# Python 3.3: Can't get a function to return anything other than None

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, return, nonetype

So, here's the relevant code:

```
def action():
    print("These are the actions you have available:")
    print("1 - Change rooms")
    print("2 - Observe the room (OUT OF ORDER)")
    print("3 - Check the room(OUT OF ORDER)")
    print("4 - Quit the game")

    choice = input("What do you do?\n> ")
    if choice in (1, "move"):
        return(1)
    elif choice in (4, "quit"):
        return(4)

play = True

while play == True:
    ###some functions that aren't relevant to the problem
    choice = action()
    print(choice)
    if choice == 1:
        change_room()
        ## more code...
```

The function always returns None. I put the print(choice) in there to see what value "choice" had and it always prinss none, and the "if choice == 1" block never runs. So I guess the function isn't returning a value at all, so the mistake is probably at the return()'s in action(), but I've checked here and elsewhere and I can't see what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`input()` returns a string, always, but you are testing against integers. Make them strings:

```
if choice in ('1', "move"):
    return 1
```

Your entered `choice` doesn't match any of your tests, so the function ends without ever reaching an explicit `return` statement and Python reverts to the default return value of `None`.

Better still, replace the whole `if/elif/elif` tree with a dictionary:

```
choices = {
    '1': 1,
    'move': 1,
    # ...
    '4': 4,
    'quit': 4,
}

if choice in choices:
    return choices[choice]
else:
    print('No such choice!')
```

Comment: Ahhh.. man, I should of tested with "move", I just obsessed trying with just the 1! If I'd tried with "move" I bet I could've figured it out. Thanks a lot Martijn. What would you say are the advantages of using a dictionary instead of the if/elif tests? It does look less convoluted/more elegant with the dict.

Comment: The mapping is more compact, easier to expand, and can be passed around if needs be. Lookups are faster too; just *one* test is needed.